# Override "all_fields" attribute within Django Rest Framework serializer through the ViewSet

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I am trying to build an API endpoint in DRF with a class-based approach.

Below are the code snippets from the Viewset and Serializer files.

organization_viewset.py:

```
class organizationViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):

    def list(self, request):
        organizations = get_all_organizations(op_format="OBJECT")
        org_serializer = OrganizationSerializer(organizations, many=True)
        return Response(org_serializer.data)
```

organization_serializer.py:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from Home.models.organization import Organization

class OrganizationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Organization
        fields = '__all__'
```

What I want to do next is, at the time of creating an instance of OrganizationSerializer, I want to pass a parameter as below:

```
org_serializer = OrganizationSerializer(organizations, many=True, all_fields=False)
```

if the all_fields value is True then I want the serializer to return all fields. Else the serializer will return the below fields.

```
fields = ('id','orgName', 'orgAltName', 'orgPlant', 'orgAddress1')
```

To solve this, I tried writing a second serializer class with the selected fields.
However, I would prefer using a single serializer class to switch between selected and all fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Django

I think you can do that easily.

First read [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/serialization/#django.core.serializers.get_serializer):

```py
your_serializer = OrganizationSerializer()
your_serializer.serialize(queryset)
data = your_serializer.getvalue()
```

That is probably the "normal" way how you utilize your serializer to get to the data.

You can pass a `fields`parameter to the `.serialize()`method. Read [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/serialization/#subset-of-fields):

```py
wanted_fields = ('id','orgName', 'orgAltName', 'orgPlant', 'orgAddress1')

your_serializer = OrganizationSerializer()
your_serializer.serialize(queryset, fields=wanted_fields)
data = your_serializer.getvalue()
```

That should just serialize specified fields.

## Django REST API

Find exactly your usecase [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#dynamically-modifying-fields)

```py
class DynamicFieldsModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """
    A ModelSerializer that takes an additional `fields` argument that
    controls which fields should be displayed.
    """

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Don't pass the 'fields' arg up to the superclass
        fields = kwargs.pop('fields', None)

        # Instantiate the superclass normally
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        if fields is not None:
            # Drop any fields that are not specified in the `fields` argument.
            allowed = set(fields)
            existing = set(self.fields)
            for field_name in existing - allowed:
                self.fields.pop(field_name)


class OrganizationSerializer(DynamicFieldsModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Organization
        fields = '__all__'
```

```py
class organizationViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):

    def list(self, request):
        fields = ('orgAltName', 'orgPlant', 'orgAddress1')
        organizations = get_all_organizations(op_format="OBJECT")
        org_serializer = OrganizationSerializer(organizations, fields=fields, many=True)
        return Response(org_serializer.data)
```

Comment: Tarquinius, first of all Thank you for attempting to solve this problem. 
I tried your solution but it looks like the DRF serializer doesn't accept the "fields" parameter. I've updated the 2nd code block with the import statement.

Comment: You are right, I missed you are using DRF.

Comment: The new solution worked for me!